# Quotient ring with reducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $S = \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)^2).$ The first goal is to show that there exist exactly two homomorphisms $ \pi\colon S\to \mathbb{C} $ such that $\pi|_{\mathbb{R}} = \text{id}_{\mathbb{R}}.$

I know that if two ideals are comaximal, say $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ and $R$ a ring, then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can write

$$ R[x]/(p(x)q(x))\cong R[x]/(p(x))\times R[x]/(q(x)).\tag{1} $$ But in this case $(p(x))=(x^2+1)=(q(x))$. If it is somehow still true that $(1)$ holds, then I think it should be pretty straightforward from there since then we would have $$ S\cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)\times\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)\cong\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}. $$ Then the only two such homomorphisms would be $ (a+bi,c+di)\mapsto (a,0) $ and $ (a+bi,c+di)\mapsto (0,c).$

Does $(1)$ hold? Or should I be doing something completely different?

Comment: You said that (1) holds if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are comaximal. How is $\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ comaximal with itself if it is not $\Bbb{R}[x]$?

Comment: Try to see under such a homomorphism, where can $x$ go.

Comment: For the record, for every complex $a \neq 0$, there is an isomorphism $S \cong \mathbb{C}[t] / t^2$, given by $x \mapsto i + at$. $a=0$ gives a homomorphism but not an isomorphism. Along with the maps $x \mapsto -i + at$, these are all of the homomorphisms.

Comment: @Hurkyl The third part of the question involves showing $S\cong\mathbb{R}[y]/(y^2).$ Is it true that $\mathbb{R}[y]/(y^2)\cong\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2)$? I don't see why that would be.

Comment: @user346096: Either the source is in error or you've copied something wrong; $S$ is clearly a four-dimensional vectors space over $\mathbb{R}$ (with basis $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$), but $\mathbb{R}[y]/(y^2)$ is only a two-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is a fourth-degree polynomial, any element in this ring is in the form of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ for $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{R}$. Since $\pi$ fixes $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{R}$, the value of $\pi$ on $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ depends solely on $\pi(x)$.

Also, since there are no zero divisors in $\Bbb{C}$, all of the zero divisors in our domain must map to $0$. This means that:
$$\pi(x^2+1)=\pi(x)^2+1=0$$
Thus, $\pi(x)=i$ or $\pi(x)=-i$, which are our two different homomorphisms.